# Summation of Fibonacci number multiplied by a variable

Tags: summation, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

I want to find a general formula for calculating:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i F_i $$

where $F_n$ is the n-th Fibonacci number.
What I have done so far is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n F_j$$

I tried to solve it using above double summation formula but it doesn't give the correct result

$F_1$ = 1,
$F_2$ = 2,
$F_3$ = 3,
$F_4$ = 5.

(for e.g. summation upto 12 is 3916, upto 5 is 46)

Comment: all your indexes are wrong/bad

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html  and https://gmatclub.com/forum/1-2x-3x-2-4x-3-nx-n-1-whats-the-sum-of-the-14985.html

Comment: As @Exodd has said, for the first formula: $\sum_{i=1}^n \color{red}{i} F_{ \color{red}{i}}$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It's way easier than that. Jordan's way to compute them is correct and leads to a close form

Comment: sorry, I have changed the indexes

Comment: @Exodd can you help me find the correct result to the summation? i feel i did some mistake in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^n iF_i$$
you can write
$$\sum_{i=1}^n iF_i =\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i F_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=j}^n F_i  $$
and switching $i,j$ it leads to
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n F_j$$
If you want to achieve a close form, you may remember
$$F_1+F_2+F_3+\dots+F_k = F_{k+2}-2$$
so
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n F_j = \sum_{i=1}^n (F_{n+2}-2 -\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} F_j ) = nF_{n+2} - 2n -  \sum_{i=1}^n(F_{i+1}-2) $$ $$= nF_{n+2} - F_{n+3}+2+F_1 =nF_{n+2} - F_{n+3} + 3 $$

Comment: The inner summation is $F_(n+2)$ - $F_(i+2)$, how do i go about solving the outer summation?

Answer (score 0):

Using finite differences:

Let $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} iF_i$

$\Delta f(n) = (n+1)F_{n+1} = \Delta (nF_{n+2} - F_{n+3})$

$\implies f(n) = nF_{n+2} - F_{n+3} + c$

For $n=1$, $f(1) = F_1 = 1 = F_3 - F_4 + c \implies c = 3$

Hence $f(n) = nF_{n+2} - F_{n+3} + 3 $